# odoo 13 500 error after updating to ubuntu 20

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

I had a version 13 Odoo working on ubuntu 18.04 with no issues.

After updating to Ubuntu 20.04 it returns a 500 error. I attempted to check the logs but after the shutdown it has no new information. I attempted to downgrade the python version to 3.6, but even after this, I am still getting the error.

What else should I be checking?

**UPDATE***

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/pull/59480

Looks like Ubuntu 20.4 is the culprit. It updated python and causes qr web to fail https://github.com/odoo/odoo/pull/59480

I downgraded to python 3.6.9 and restart the service but still getting the 500 error.

Comment: The Apache logs, if it's being served by Apache?

Comment: @snake. Thaks didn't even think about that. I checked my webserver but nothing so far looks like it is a python issue.